# When update displayName of Authenticated user ? displayName not load until refreshing page

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have this function for updating current user displayName

```
  updateDisplayName(nameForm) {

       if(nameForm.value.name === this.user.displayName) {
          this.error = "Error: You used old name."
         return
       }

       this.resetError();

       var userRef = this.firebasePathCreator(this.currentUserId);

       if (this.checkIfUserExists(this.currentUserId)) {
         return userRef.update({
         'displayName': nameForm.value.name,
         'photoURL': ''
      }).then(() => { this.navigateTo('/account'); });
      } else {
      return userRef.set({
         'email': this.currentEmail,
         'displayName': nameForm.value.name,
         'photoURL': ''
      }).then(() => { this.navigateTo('/account'); });
      }
      }
```

this update the display name in both realtime database and authentication section. but when I route to "/account", displayName not change until I refresh the page.

html code

```
<div class="large-6 columns">
        <form [formGroup]="nameForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(nameForm)">
     <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <h5>Change your name</h5>                        
                <label [ngClass]="{error: (this.auth.error)  }">
                    Full name
                    <input type="text" formControlName="name" value="{{ this.auth.currentUser.displayName }}">
                </label>
                <span class="error" *ngIf="this.auth.error">{{ this.auth.error }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button small">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide the HTML code as well ?

Comment: I update the post

Comment: Are you updating `this.auth` after updating displayName?

Comment: No, this code when name update  return userRef.update({
              'displayName': nameForm.value.name,
              'photoURL': ''
            }).then(() => { this.navigateTo('/account'); });

Comment: You need to update `this.auth.currentUser.displayName` before you change route.